# How do I prove the existence of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove the existence of
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}$$
When $y=0$ the limits is $0$

when $y=-x$ it´s $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2(-x^2)}{x^3- x^3}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2(-x^2)}{0}$$

I can concluir that the limit no exist??
or how proof the existence?

Comment: when $y=-x$ the function is not defined !

Comment: BUT WHAT DO I conclude WITH THIS??

Comment: You conclude that the limit does not exist, because in every deleted neighborhood of $p = (0,0)$ (i.e., every open set containing $p$ from which $p$ has been removed) contains points for which $f(x,y) = x^2y^2/(x^3 + y^3)$ is not defined

Comment: See also [Limit of $x^2y^2/x^3+y^3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/220453) and [Nonexistence of the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/538770).

Answer (score 3):

Along the path $y=x$, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3} = \frac{1}{2}x\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
However, along the path $y=x^3-x$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3} = \frac{x^8-2x^6+x^4}{x^9+3x^5-3x^7},
\end{align*}
which does not have a finite limit when $x\rightarrow 0$.
That is, 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}
\end{align*}
does not exist.

Comment: ok,, thanks,, gordon

Comment: I do not thing this is correct, the limit along this path is in fact zero. See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B8%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D%7Bx%5E3%2Bx%7D|. However, non-existence of this limit is shown in other linked questions.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: the problem you have observed does exist, and is now fixed.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking. After your last modification you get an expression which has limit $+\infty$ for $x\to0^+$ and $-\infty$ for $x\to0^-$. So to make this completely correct, you should either say that you are using $y=x^3-x$ only for positive $x$. (Or say that limit does not exists instead of saying that limit is $+\infty$.) I hope I did not miss something. Here is [Wolframalpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0+(x%5E8-2x%5E6%2Bx%5E4)%2F(x%5E9%2B3x%5E5-3x%5E7)).

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak. further revision is made.